# Selenium can't find chromedriver after cloning project to Windows machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I built a Rails application on a Linux machine using Selenium, and placed my chromedriver right into the root folder. In other words, my app is named "seleniumapp" and the absolute path of my chromedriver is just `seleniumapp/chromedriver`. I never had any problems with the file being located. But I just cloned my app onto a Windows machine, and I'm suddenly getting this error:

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError in Pages#home
>
> Showing C:/Users/Joey/Documents/seleniumapp/app/views/pages/home.html.erb where line #28 raised:
>
> Unable to find chromedriver. Please download the server from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver.

As a shot in the dark, I thought PATH may have been referring to my Windows environment variables, so I added my chromedriver path to my Windows PATH, but nothing changed.

How can I make Selenium find my chromedriver file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you have to put the driver in the PATH or you should call before you initialize the driver.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = <path to chromedriver>
```

Comment: I put `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = "chromedriver"` but it's telling me "chromedriver is not a file".

Comment: you have to indicate full path of chrome driver here.

Comment: That is the full path, I think. I also tried "/chromedriver", with the same result.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't add the extension. It should have been "chromedriver.exe".

Comment: @Prany can you pls check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72569369/getting-white-screen-when-running-selenium-automation